# Gradient of a sum

Tags: deep-learning, mathematics, generative-models

I have a neural net (BEGAN Generative Adversarial Network) where I need to apply this formula:
[image]

And this one:
[image]

So I made an operator that does each operation and outputs a value for each losses.

Now, I need to compute the gradients. I guess my gradient takes 4 inputs (Ld, Lg, kT+1, and MGlobal) and outputs 3 ((grad kT, grad Lx, grad L(G(zd))). Can somebody explain to me what would they be? Those are constants dependent on each others, I am not sure what to put.

Many thanks for who could explain this to me.

Comment: It would help to draw out the computation graph (or view it using Tensorboard if you are working with Tensorflow/Keras). Have a look at some good examples in the [CS231n course website](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/#staged). Perhaps watch [lecture 4 of the course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i94OvYb6noo).